# Non-free projective modules for a Universal Enveloping Algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras

Let g be a finite dimensional Lie algebra over k, and let U be its universal enveloping Lie algebra.  Is there a left module M of U which is projective but not free?  That is, is the Quillen-Suslin theorem still true for enveloping algebras?

Quillen-Suslin says this there are no non-free projectives for S(g), the associated graded algebra of U.  Thus, if the associated graded module of a projective is projective, then it is free (and so the original module was also free).  Therefore, this question is equivalent to the question "Is the associated graded module of a projective U-module always projective?"

My guess is no, because the Weyl algebra has non-free projectives, even though it's associated graded algebra is a polynomial algebra.  However, the tricks I know that work for the Weyl algebra don't work for Lie algebras.  I would love a simple example of a non-free projective U-module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=CM_1985__54_1_63_0) Stafford shows that whenever g is a finite-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra the enveloping algebra has non-free but stably free (and therefore projective) right ideals. He also shows how to construct them.